# Nuget Packages Creation JQuery Bug

Tags: c#, jquery, tfs, nuget

I create my own nuget packages using Microsoft TFS and whenever I install my nuget packages in any solution it auto adds jQuery folder, how to avoid that and not install jQuery with my Nuget

Answer (score 0):

It should not be a bug.

You need to check your own nuget packages first, you may packaged the jQuery related things in it. Or the packages have external dependencies on JavaScript libraries (*Reference below screenshot*). In this case, if you are sure that you don't need the jQuery, then you can re-create the nuget package.

Another possibility is that your projects referenced the jQuery libraries. Just  to check that, If they referenced the jQuery libraries then the nuget will automatically restore the packages.

[image]

Comment: @Ahmed Swahel Have you checked that? Have you got the answer about the doubt? any update?